# What is the proper way to thanks a professor for asking me to TA for her course?

Tags: sentence-usage

I want to thank a professor for asking me to TA for her course, because it made me happy that she had thought of me for the position. As a non-native English learner, it is sometimes hard for me to get the feeling of sentences. I want to know which of the following two sentences works best in this setting.

> I would be very happy to TA for the course. *Thanks for **asking** me*.

> I would be very happy to TA for the course. *Thanks for **reaching out to** me*.

Comment: I would say “Thank you for the opportunity.”

Comment: Also "Thank you for thinking of me."

Comment: You want to know which of the two works **better** rather than works **best**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both are appropriate and reasonable in a professional or academic context.** There are slight differences in formality level and connotation, but in this case it is unlikely to matter.

"Reaching out" sounds a little more formal or distant, while "asking" sounds a little more familiar. Personally, I would probably write "reaching out" if I was corresponding with someone I had never met or spoken to before, and I would use "asking" if I knew the recipient (even only professionally). If you really want to emphasize the formality, you could also replace "thanks" with "thank you," but that might come across as overly stiff or distant to some people. It all depends on your academic culture, which varies significantly by location. When in doubt, mimic the style of writing that you see others use.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestions are both good.  I'd prefer "asking me" over "reaching out", because it is simpler.

Alternatives from comments:

> “Thank you for the opportunity.”

> "Thank you for thinking of me."